# Continuation Monad Working

Tags: haskell, monads, continuations

I'm trying to wrap my head around this following piece of code:

```
ex2 = do
  a <- return 1
  b <- Cont (\fred -> fred 10)
  return $ a + b

ghci > runCont ex2 show
"11"
```

How is String "11" the output of the function ? I get that part that the show function converts the 10 to String, but then how does `a + b` take place since String numerals can't sum up ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is that `a` and `b` have type `Int`, and the conversion to a `String` with `show` is only done *after* `a` and `b` are summed.

If you need further convincing, ask yourself if you have any problem with

```
runCont ex2 id
```

or

```
runCont ex2 (\a -> a * a)
```

---

If you need even more convincing, note that the type definition and monad instance are

```
data Cont r a = Cont { runCont :: (a -> r) -> r }

instance Monad (Cont r) where
  return a = Cont ($a)
```

so you can squint a bit and convince yourself that your example is equivalent to

```
ex = do
  a <- return 1
  b <- return 10
  return (a + b)
```

which is just

```
ex = return (1 + 10)
```

Comment: It might be even more illuminating to include the definition of `>>=` and explain how `Cont (\fred -> fred 10)` is equivalent to `return 10`.